# What is the Purpose of Adding a Keychain Wrapper to my iOS app?

Tags: ios, keychain

I am just stuck trying to understand what is the real purpose of having a keychain wrapper if, for example, I am being asked to create one that just runs in foreground, and when the app enters background, then its data should be deleted?

Anyone with a possible explanation for the above? Also, what is the difference between Keychain wrapper and a NSMutableDictionary, or are they complement to each other.

Look at what I am being asked to do: *create a Keychain wrapper that runs only in the foreground. If an "entering background" notification is found, remove data from memory.*

Any help will be very appreciated!

Comment: "what is the difference between Keychain wrapper and a NSMutableDictionary" - the one is a keychain wrapper, the other is an NSMutableDictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming by Keychain wrapper here, it's meant as a wrapper around Apple's keychain services. If that's the case, then the point of the wrapper is to make it easier for you to use Apple's keychain secure storage.

Normally, the reason you would want to use Apple's keychain service is to store secure credentials. For example, if you wanted to have a 'save login' feature, then username/password could be stored in keychain services for when app is launched again.

If there is no desire to persist secure data, then you don't need keychain services.

NSMutableDictionary, is the mutable version of objective-c's key value pair data structure.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My app is required to erase the keychain wrapper data from memory when the app goes to the background. However, as part of another requirement, when the app is again put in foreground, it should ask the user for his/her credentials, but if I erase the keychain content, how is the user supposed to be able to login if those credentials were already deleted? Does that make sense to you ? I could be misunderstanding the whole thing, hopefully you can provide me with a possible clarification.

Comment: are you authenticating to a remote server?

Comment: For the moment I am authenticating directly to the database created by my app, but in the future this will be done against a server.

Comment: I have not worked with non-remote login, but off the top of my head, you could just store user/pass in keychain services when user creates account, then next time they log in, just check the entered credentials against the credentials in the keychain. Have a look at uickeychain on github. Also, it sounds like maybe you are working on a project for a non-technical client. In the case, I have found in my experiences that interpreting specifications precisely as written may not always be ideal.